# Ubuntu 20.0.4 Autoinstall ISO not working on UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi

My custom Ubuntu server 20.0.4 ISO does not "detect" my user-data file. It boots into the regular installation when booted on UEFI. If I boot the same ISO in legacy mode, the installation goes unattended and finishes successfully.

I have edited the following files:

- boot/grub/grub.cfg
- boot/grub/loopback.cfg
- isolinux/txt.cfg

Does anyone know what could possibly be missing?

Comment: When you make the custom iso file, you have probably only fixed booting in legacy mode. You must also fix it in UEFI mode. And you must check that secure boot is turned off.

Comment: Thanks for helping @sudodus
How do I fix in UEFI mode? Forgot about secure boot.

Comment: Start by inspecting the standard Ubuntu iso file. In UEFI mode the bootloader is in the EFI System Partition 'ESP'. Maybe you have already copied it, but other things might have changed in your iso file, so that it points in the wrong direction. You can also check how grub-efi works, read the manual and some tutorial via the internet carefully, and then use the 'trial and error' method. I have used the grub method in [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) but corresponding to 'installed system' not to make an iso file, so it may not be quite relevant in your case.

Comment: Anyway, if you wish, inspect the code of `dus-persistent` (a bash shellscript which is part of mkusb).

Comment: If you upload your custom iso file somewhere, I can try to make a bootable USB drive from it. I will not make an iso file, that works in UEFI mode when cloned, but I will try a few things using your current version of iso file and let you know the results.